# Relationship between groupoid morphisms and the induced functor on their categories of actions?

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

This is similar to a [question I asked recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749061/if-the-functor-on-presheaf-categories-given-by-precomposition-by-f-is-ff-is-f-f), but this time specifically for groupoids.

Suppose $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a groupoid morphism. Let $f^\ast: [B, \text{Set}] \rightarrow [A, \text{Set}]$ be the functor given by precomposition by $f$, so that $G: B \rightarrow \text{Set}$ maps to $G \circ f : A \rightarrow \text{Set}$. I'm wondering if the following statements are true:

1) $f$ is essentially surjective and full if and only if $f^\ast$ is full an faithful.

2) $f$ is an equivalence if and only if $f^\ast$ is an equivalence.

I think I have the forward directions for both of these statements, and proofs by contradiction for the reverse direction of (1). [Zhen Lin's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5191/zhen-lin) answer to my previous question tells me that (2) holds, since groupoids are isomorphic to their Cauchy completions (their only indempotents are identities). However, I would really appreciate a proof sketch of (2), and (constructively) the reverse direction of (1), since I am pretty stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think (2) is entirely constructive. The proof can be found [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/163855/11640).

Comment: Thanks! Constructive may have been too strong, I was more looking for a 'direct' proof. I am already in a world with axiom of choice, so constructivity left me long ago.